# Cargar de forma dinámica varias filas de un ArrayList en JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Es un problema de lógica o de no usar los elementos adecuados. Estoy con JavaFX utilizando el JDK 9.

***Contexto:*** He creado el típico escenario de un jugador que hace rebotar una bola para destruir bloques (imagen para ubicarnos): 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La lógica del programa funciona (choques, destrucción de cubos, coques con los laterales  y  movimientos) a excepción de una cosa.

***Problema:*** La creación de los cubos que hay que destruir. Para las pruebas generé una sola línea de cubos, cuando quise ampliar esta línea a varias decidí usar una matriz simple para almacenar los cubos a destruir, mi problema viene al rellenar la matriz, ya que cada cubo posee una posición X y otra Y y a no ser que lo hago a mano como muestro a continuación, no se me ocurre como hacer esto para que sea dinámico y se generen los cubos que se deseen (solo pensando en que se maneja una matriz con una cantidad predeterminada de filas y columnas). 
**Nota importante:** En un inicio usaba un ArrayList para que la lista fuera dinámica, la decisión pasó a matriz para intentar controlar la creación de cubos, en ver de eliminar un elemento de la matriz lo muevo fuera de la pantalla.
Os pongo el código que he generado, como veis generé dos líneas pero el primer cubo de cada línea esta puesto explicitamente cuando solo debería poner de manera explicita el primer cubo y el resto partan de esas posiciones para pintar el resto.

Al inicio tenemos algunas variables que necesitaremos, así como la matriz.

```
    //control creacion cubos
boolean creacionCubos = true;
private int FILAS_CUBOS = 5;
private int COLUMNAS_CUBOS = 14;

public static ArrayList<Cubo> cubos = new ArrayList<>();

public Cubo[][] cubos2 = new Cubo[FILAS_CUBOS][COLUMNAS_CUBOS];
```

Posteriormente el método para crear y cargar los cubos:

```
    //Metodo para crear y cargar los cubos en la matriz
    public void cargarCubos() {
        for (int i = 0; i < FILAS_CUBOS - 1; i++) {
            for (int a = 0; a < COLUMNAS_CUBOS-1; a++) {

                //Posiciono el primer cubo
                if (i == 0 && a == 0) {
                    cubos2[i][a] = new Cubo(10, 400);
                } else if (i == 0 && a != 0) {
                    //Cubos restantes de la primera fila
                    cubos2[i][a] = (new Cubo(cubos2[i][a-1].pos_x_cubo  + ANCHO_CUBO + 5, cubos2[i][a - 1].pos_y_cubo));
                } else if(i == 1 && a == 0) {
                    //Cubo segunda fila
                    cubos2[i][a] = new Cubo(cubos2[0][0].pos_x_cubo, cubos2[0][0].getPos_y_cubo()-ALTO_CUBO -5 );
                } else if(i == 1 && a != 0){
                    //Cubos restantes segunda fila
                    cubos2[i][a] = (new Cubo(cubos2[i][a-1].pos_x_cubo  + ANCHO_CUBO + 5, cubos2[i][a - 1].pos_y_cubo));                       
                } else {
                    cubos2[i][a] = new Cubo(10, 400);
                }
            }

        }
```

A continuación pongo como se llama a esta matriz para "pintar" los cubos en pantalla:

```
        //Cargar cubos
    for (int i = 0; i < FILAS_CUBOS - 1; i++) {
        for (int a = 0; a < COLUMNAS_CUBOS - 1; a++) {
            gc.fillRect(cubos2[i][a].pos_x_cubo, cubos2[i][a].pos_y_cubo, Cubo.ANCHO_CUBO, Cubo.ALTO_CUBO);        

        }
    }
```

La clase Cubo cuenta con un simple constructor para darle posición x e y, además de dos variables estáticas para determinar ANCHO y ALTO:

```
        //cubos tamaño
    public static final int ALTO_CUBO = 10;
    public static final int ANCHO_CUBO = 30;

    private int pos_x_cubo;
    private int pos_y_cubo;

    //constructor cubo
    public Cubo(int x, int y) {
        pos_x_cubo = x;
        pos_y_cubo = y;
```

Se agradecen todos los comentarios, ya sean para arreglar el problema, para mejorar el código, clases que pueda utilizar y cualquier tipo de información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como me imaginaba era un problema de lógica, me ha costado un poco pero al final lo he sacado. Supongo que hay cosas más eficientes pero modificando el método que controla la instaciación de los cubos he logrado llegar al objetivo y ahora puedo controlar la cantidad de filas y cubos por fila con las dos variables.

El método quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
        //Metodo para crear y cargar los cubos
    public void cargarCubos() {

        for (int i = 0; i < FILAS_CUBOS; i++) {
            for (int a = 0; a < COLUMNAS_CUBOS; a++) {

                //Posiciono el primer cubo de cada columna
                if (i == 0) {
                    if (a == 0) {
                        //Posición del primer cubo
                        cubos2[i][a] = new Cubo(10, 400);
                    } else {
                        //cubos restantes primera fila 
                        cubos2[i][a] = (new Cubo(cubos2[i][a-1].pos_x_cubo + ANCHO_CUBO +5, cubos2[i][a-1].pos_y_cubo));
                    }
                } else if(i != 0 && a == 0){
                    //primer cubo siguientes  de las columnas
                    cubos2[i][a] = (new Cubo(cubos2[i-1][a].pos_x_cubo, cubos2[i-1][a].pos_y_cubo - ALTO_CUBO - 5));                 
                } else {
                        //cubos restantes de las siguientes filas
                        cubos2[i][a] = (new Cubo(cubos2[i][a-1].pos_x_cubo + ANCHO_CUBO + 5, cubos2[i][a-1].pos_y_cubo));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```